# Fetch number of rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I'm trying to fetch number of rows that were not in another table and show them using javascript.

First, in the main page, it will list the *inbox name* from `inboxtb` table. Then I have a script that should pass the value (`inboxid`) to another file and return the number of result back to the main file, in its corresponding row.

I'll fetch first all the inbox row (*main page*):

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
  echo '<li><a href="#" data-artid="'.$inboxid.'" id="loadmessage">'.$name.'</a> <span id="loadnumber"></span></li>';
}
```

Then my script:

```
$(function(){
  $('.loadmessage').ready(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    var dataString = "inboxid="+elem.attr('data-artid');
    var $parent = $(this).closest('loadmessage');
      setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "noofres.php",
          data: dataString,
          success: function(data) {
            var $span = $parent.find('.loadnumber'); /* FIND THE CORRESPONDING SPAN */
            $span.append(data); /* LOAD THE DATA INSIDE THE SPAN */
          }
        });
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
```

And my noofres.php:

```
if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT a.messageid FROM messagetb a LEFT JOIN readtb b ON a.messageid = b.messageid WHERE a.inboxid = ? AND b.readid IS NULL")){
  $stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET["inboxid"]);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $noofunreadmessages = $stmt->num_rows;
  $stmt->close();
} /* END OF SECOND PREPARED STATEMENT */

echo '<span class="badges">'.$noofunreadmessages.'</span>';
```

But it doesn't return the numbers, where it should. What am I doing wrong? Or a better script to do it?

Very rough example output:

```
Person1 Message - 3
Person2 Message - 1
Person3 Message - 10
```

But my current output is:

```
Person1 Message
Person2 Message
Person3 Message
```

Number does not return the corresponding number at all. And error are showing up and continuously growing with this message.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect in terms of logic.
You are executing AJAX **once** and receiving the value **once** as well.
Then, you update your element's HTML **many times** with **the same** one value.

```
$.ajax({}, {
    success: function(data) {
       setInterval(function() {            
           $('#loadunreadmessages').html(data); 
       }, 1000);
    }
});
```

In order to get fresh values every time, you need to change it such way that it will execute AJAX **many times** and every time it will update value **once**. It sounds logical.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({}, {
        success: function(data) {
           $('#loadunreadmessages').html(data); 
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

In your case it is:

```
setInterval(function() { /* EVERY SECOND, IT EXECUTES NEW REQUEST TO GET FRESH VALUES */
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../fetch/noofres.php", /* THIS IS WHERE THE NUMBER OF UNREAD MESSAGES SHOULD COME FROM */
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#loadunreadmessages').html(data); /* LOAD THE NUMBER TO THIS SPAN WITH THE ID OF loadunreadmessages */
        }
    })  ;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But it doesn't resolve the main problem. It does not return the number of unread messages from the `noofres.php` file.

Comment: @LoganWayne What kind of error occurs? If you open `noofres.php` directly in browser file and there will be unread messages - will it generate proper HTML `span`? If yes, then there is definitely a JS error which should have appeared in browser console.

Comment: There is no error in the JS  in my browser console. The current problem now is that it only shows 0 in the first row.